# how do I free memory of these .txt files

Tags: windows, delphi-7

Working with TXT files I've been seeing a message lately "cannot create file ('c:\01.txt') the process cannot acess the file because it is being used by another process" how do I free memory of these .txt files?

I have this code by Mr. Nice and when i trying to change or add new using: ListBox1.Items.savetofile('01.txt');

"cannot create file ('c:\01.txt') the process cannot acess the file because it is being used by another process"

```
var
  path: string;
  SR: TSearchRec;
  tempFile: TextFile;
  line: string;
begin
  path:= 'C:\my all txt\';
  if FindFirst(path + '*.txt', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if (SR.Attr <> faDirectory) then
      begin
        AssignFile(tempFile, path + SR.Name);
        Reset(tempFile);
        while not Eof(tempFile) do
        begin
          Readln(tempFile, line);
          ListBox1.Items.Add(line);
        end;
      end;
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
    FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close files after you're finished with them. You need to use `CloseFile` once you've reached `Eof(tempfile)`:

```
while not Eof(tempfile) do
begin
  Readln(tempfile, line);
  ListBox1.Items.Add(line);
end;
CloseFile(tempfile);
```

Comment: An alternative solution would be to get rid of the `TextFile` I/O altogether and just use `TStrings.LoadFromFile()` instead, eg: `lines := TStringList.Create; try repeat ... lines.LoadFromFile(path + SR.Name); ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(lines); ... until ...; finally lines.Free; end;`

Comment: @Remy Leabeu I made some changes and it also worked. I'll see which one looks better in my application. thanks

Comment: @Ken White this worked perfectly.. I just added CloseFile(tempfile), thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I started to write an implementation using TStringList, and then decided it was outside the scope of the question asked.